# Navigating between Express, EJS and Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, adobe-brackets

How do I create a page which has a button, which `onclick()` will redirect to another page?

Comment: This question is asking multiple questions at once. 1) How do I send a request when a button is clicked. 2) How do I respond to the request and redirect to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

This would go to www.stackoverflow.com You can substitute anything for that of course.

In HTML:

```
button(onclick='redirect(www.stackoverflow.com)') Button!
```

In JS:

```
function redirect(res){
      window.location = res;
    }
```